# sbt key that corresponds to command that I type in

Tags: sbt

I want to make my tests run every time I type `universal:package-zip-tarball`. I know that to do this, I have to put something like

```
someKey <<= someKey dependsOn (test in Test)
```

in my `project/Build.scala`, where `someKey` is the key that provides the task I want to depend on the test run, in this case, `universal:package-zip-tarball`.

But my generic question is: how do I find out what `someKey` should be?

Note that this is a Play framework project, and I don't even know if `universal:package-zip-tarball` is provided by Play, or by some other sbt plugin.

Is there any way sbt can just tell me, without me having to go searching for the source code repository containing the relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `inspect` command:

```
$ inspect universal:package-zip-tarball
```

[...]

```
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.UniversalPlugin)
UniversalPlugin.scala:73
```

This is actually the location of the definition of the code of the task, but this is close enough to help, because it lets us find the key (the key will be in the same sbt plugin).

From this we can find out that the key is:

```
com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Keys.packageZipTarball
```

Unfortunately, just substituting this in doesn't work - it says:

```
[error] Reference to undefined setting: 
[error] 
[error]   my-project/*:packageZipTarball from my-project/*:packageZipTarball
[error]      Did you mean my-project/universal-docs:packageZipTarball ?
[error]  
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

So to fix this, the only thing remaining is to translate the `universal:` prefix. It is in fact this:

```
packageZipTarball in Universal <<= packageZipTarball in Universal dependsOn (test in Test)
```

but it just needs an extra import to make it compile:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
```

(In this case, `SbtNativePackager` is the main plugin object, I think. Other plugins might require importing something else, to translate such a prefix.)